# Bash+Expect script not working in cron RHEL 7

Tags: bash, cron, expect, rhel7

I have the below script which is working in the terminal but not in crontab.Why it is not running in cron

Note:/opt/app/bin/app.exe is having a CLI

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/opt/app/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/myuser/.local/bin:/home/myuser/bin:/home/myuser/scripts

ip=10.12.13.4
file=filename

function filestats(){
        /usr/bin/expect - $1 $2 << 'EOF' | awk  '/^second line/ { print $5 }'
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set file [lindex $argv 1]

set timeout 60

spawn /opt/app/bin/app.exe 127.0.0.1 $ip 1112

expect {
        "CLI# > " { send "addip $file\r" }
}

sleep 3
expect {
        "CLI# > " { send "quit\r" }
}
EOF
}
filestats ${ip} ${file}
```

Comment: Show the crontab entry.

Comment: Are there any environment variables that the app requires, that you have set in your environment, that need to be added to this script?

Comment: */3 * * * * /home/myuser/scripts/script.sh  2> /tmp/crontab_script_log 2>&1

Comment: I have also tried to give crontab as shown below as well, but issue was not solved
*/3 * * * * /bin/bash /home/myuser/scripts/script.sh 2> /tmp/crontab_script_log 2>&1

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Have a careful read of [the cron tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) which has a lot of troubleshooting advice.

Answer (score 0):

EOF was not really exiting the loop. I made it to `expect eof` just above the EOF which fixed the issue. I have noticed this issue only in RHEL 7, not in RHEL 6